# dask dataframe to parquet fails with memory error

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I created dask dataframe from multiple hdfs files and then tried to write back the final dataframe to hdfs(parquet). But it failed with Memory Error message.

```
dask_df=<some initialization>
for parquet_hdfs_path in hdfs_files:
    df=dd.read_parquet(parquet_hdfs_path)
    dask_df = dask_df.join(df)

dask_df.to_parquet(...)
```

Final dask dataframe would have 1million records and 600 columns.

Dask cluster size: 5 Nodes with 55G memory each.

Exception:

```
File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 957, in to_parquet
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     return to_parquet(path, self, *args, **kwargs)
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet.py", line 445, in to_parquet
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     writes = delayed(writes).compute()
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 99, in compute
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 206, in compute
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     results = get(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1934, in get
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     results = self.gather(packed, asynchronous=asynchronous)
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1376, in gather
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     asynchronous=asynchronous)
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 548, in sync
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 241, in sync
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     six.reraise(*error[0])
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     raise value
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :   File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 229, in f
[ worker demo4-dn-1 ] :     result[0] = yield make_coro()
```

Please point me in right direction to overcome this problem.

Comment: I recommend including the exception and full traceback in your question.

Comment: @MRocklin, I have added the exception now.

Comment: @MRocklin: I know it's not right place to ask but would be you available to for small chat about dask :)